# How to spawn randomly without the next spawning object spawning near

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a personal project which is about an aim trainer. What I'm trying to do is that the object that spawns randomly doesn't spawn near the previous one.
I'm not very good at mathematical logic so what I've tried to do doesn't work. Any ideas, thanks :)

The code I've tried isn't doing what I want, the spawns randoms keep appearing near the last spawn, and I don't want that. What I really want is not to repeat the position of the last spawn.

I tried this:

```
public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour 
{

 public Vector3 GerRandomPosition()
    {
        Vector3 center = boxCollider.center + transform.position;

        float minX = center.x - boxCollider.size.x / 2f;
        float maxX = center.x + boxCollider.size.x / 2f;

        float minY = center.y - boxCollider.size.y / 2f;
        float maxY = center.y + boxCollider.size.y / 2f;

        auxRandomX = randomX;
        randomX = Random.Range(minX, maxX);

        auxRandomY = randomY;
        randomY = Random.Range(minY, maxY);

        float distanceX = Mathf.Abs(auxRandomX - randomX);

        while (distanceX < 3.2f)
        {
            randomX = Random.Range(minX, maxX);
            distanceX = Mathf.Abs(auxRandomX - randomX);
        }

        float distanceY = Mathf.Abs(auxRandomY - randomY);

        while (distanceY < 3.2f)
        {
            randomY = Random.Range(minY, maxY);
            distanceY = Mathf.Abs(auxRandomY - randomY);
        }
      
        Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, transform.position.z);

        return randomPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with regards to how your code is NOT doing what you want?  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** Move/Check the previous spawn point with a set distance spacing.

---

#### Bruteforce Solution

```cs
Vector3 lastSpawnPoint = Vector3.zero; // or somewhere far away for start

const float SPAWN_SPACING = 1f;

public Vector3 GetSpawnPoint(){

    // Keep generating a new position until it is far away from the previous spawn point
    Vector3 newPoint;
    do {
        newPoint = GetRandomPosition();
    } while (Vector3.Distance(newPoint, lastSpawnPoint) <= SPAWN_SPACING)
    // Shouldn't be a long/infinite loop if the play-area is big enough.

    lastSpawnPoint = newPoint;
    return newPoint;
}
```

Bruteforce it, works very nicely if your game has a large playing/spawning field.

---

#### No Bruteforce Solution

```cs
Vector3 lastSpawnPoint = Vector3.zero;

const float MIN_SPAWN_SPACING = 1f;
const float MAX_SPAWN_SPACING = 10f;

public Vector3 GetSpawnPoint(){
    if (lastSpawnPoint == Vector3.zero){
        return GetRandomPosition();
    }

    // We generate a direction and spacing,
    // and move the spawn-point based on that.
    float spacing = Random.Range(MIN_SPAWN_SPACING, MAX_SPAWN_SPACING);
    Vector3 direction = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized;

    lastSpawnPoint += (direction * spacing);
    return lastSpawnPoint;
}
```

Works nicely, and you can set a max spawn spacing too.
Though currently it is able to generate anywhere, so you might want to configure this to limit where it can spawn at.

Comment: Hiii , first of all, thank you very much. I have only one doubt, what do u mean with "GetRandomPoint()"   ??

Comment: @Anon `GetRandomPoint()` is same as `GetRandomPosition()`; Fixed it to prevent confusion. The check is there just for the very first spawn.

Comment: Hello, it is not very clear to me where to implement the solution. Could you tell me where ? Where would you call GetSpawnPoint ? Thanks

Comment: @PHCode No one here will ever have a clear answer to that, it really depends on how you have structured your code, and how you want to structure it. Though you can put it at your Spawn code and it should work fine.